# ajax call returns 404

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to submit my form to the controller as JSON data to be further processed. I am using jquery to and use following code to submit the data:

My js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('hi');
        $("#btn-save").click(function(event) {
               var data = {}
               alert($("#name").val());
            data["name"] = $("#name").val();
            data["address"] = $("#address").val();
            data["phone"] = $("#phone").val();
            data["zipCode"] = $("#zipCode").val();
            $("#btn-save").prop("disabled", true);
            alert('1'+JSON.stringify(data));
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 url: "/saveUser",
                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                 dataType: 'json',
                 timeout: 600000,
                 success: function (data) {
                    alert('success');
                 },
                 error: function(xhr, status, error){
                     var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                     alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                 }
        });
           });
    });
</script>
```

I have written my controller class which is expected to handle the requests. but the execution never reaches this method.
This is expected to call the controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody SysUserDto  saveUser(@RequestBody SysUserDto user) {
    System.out.println("Save code******");
    return user;
}
```

I even tried with out response body and having the return as void instead of SysUserDto
But i see 404 error as the execution goes to error block. Please help

Comment: By any chance the Controller class is not component scanned ?

Comment: Can you access the saveUser-Url directly (after changing RequestMethod to GET)?

Comment: Getting  Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported] when i tried to access the URL http://localhost:8010/OMS/saveUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tried this. assuming your form id is called 'uploadForm'

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            alert('hi');
            $("#btn-save").click(function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             var user= new FormData($('#uploadForm')[0]);        
                $.ajax({
                    contentType : false,
                    processData : false,
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: "/saveUser",
                     data: user,
                     timeout: 600000,
                     success: function (data) {
                        alert('success');
                     },
                     error: function(xhr, status, error){
                         var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                         alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                     }
            });
               });
        });
    </script>
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String saveUser(SysUserDto user) {
    System.out.println("Save code******");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
    System.out.println(json);
    return json;
}
```

`ObjectMapper` is from jackson library.